# Unorderable types in Python: NoneType() and int(). Using an interface to make this method

Tags: python, parsing, typeerror, nonetype

I am in the finishing stages of finishing up a project that is due on July 6, 2015 to get all the errors fixed. I seem to have run across an error in which I have no discern-able answer:

```
  File "Z:\Jordan White's Folder\Concepts of Programming CS 4150 Summer Semester 2015\Projects\cs4150pythonproject\BooleanExpressions.py", line 30, in evaluate
value = self.expr1.evaluate() < self.expr2.evaluate()
  TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
```

The line is pointing to line 30 in this code:

```
 '''
 Created on Jun 22, 2015

 @author: JordanWhite
 '''

 from RelationalOperators import RelationalOperator
 class BooleanExpression():

def __init__(self, op, expr1, expr2):
    if expr1 == None or expr2 == None:
        raise Exception("null expression argument")
    self.op = op
    self.expr1 = expr1
    self.expr2 = expr2

def evaluate(self):
    value = True
    int(0 if value is None else value)
    if self.op == RelationalOperator.EQ_OP:
        value = self.expr1.evaluate() == self.expr2.evaluate()
    elif self.op == RelationalOperator.NE_OP:
        value = self.expr1.evaluate() != self.expr2.evaluate()
    elif self.op == RelationalOperator.GE_OP:
        value = self.expr1.evaluate() >= self.expr2.evaluate()
    elif self.op == RelationalOperator.GT_OP:
        value = self.expr1.evaluate() > self.expr2.evaluate()
    elif self.op == RelationalOperator.LE_OP:
        value = self.expr1.evaluate() <= self.expr2.evaluate()
    elif self.op == RelationalOperator.LT_OP:
        value = self.expr1.evaluate() < self.expr2.evaluate()
    return value
```

The expr1 variable is somehow being registered as a NoneType, when it is meant to be an int() variable. Expression is an interface, as shown here:

```
'''
Created on Jun 18, 2015

@author: JordanWhite
'''
class Expression():

    def evaluate(self):
        pass
```

The goal is when the boolean expression is evaluated, it prints out in the Parser as true, and when it's true, it fetches the value of x := 12 in the Pascal program here:

```
Program a ;

begin
    x := 4 ;
    if < x 7 then
        x := 12 
    else
        x := 14 ;
    write ( x )
end .
```

How on earth do I fix something like this, where I can get rid of the unorderable types error and then move on with fixing more errors?

Comment: `evaluate(self):` returns `None` by default as do all function/methods that don't specify a return value, you cannot compare different types in python3

Comment: Don't test for equality with `None`; use `if expr1 is None or expr2 is None:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- `int(0 if value is None else value)` doesn't accomplish anything because you are not saving the result -- maybe you meant `value = int(...)`?
- `value = self.expr1.evaluate() < self.expr2.evaluate()`  The `self.expr1.evaluate()` call is returning `None`, which is what causes your problem.  So your next step is figure out why `None` is being returned from that expression.  Note that `self.expr1` is *not* None, its `evaluate` method is *returning* None.

Comment: Note that `self.expr1` isn't necessarily (and probably isn't) an instance of `BooleanExpression`, so you'll have to check the `evaluate` method in your other classes to find the culprit.